# Map stored procedure to enity framework apart from CRUD

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have understood the following code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("sp_InsertStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name").Result(rs => rs.Student_ID, "Student_ID"))
        .Update(sp => sp.HasName("sp_UpdateStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name"))
        .Delete(sp => sp.HasName("sp_DeleteStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.Student_ID, "Id"))
        );
}
```

But still I have few questions
1. If I have button called calculate and want to call some other procedure apart from CRUD. How can I call that SP?
2. How can I pass list of model/entity (collection) to procedure as parameter? or any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your `DbContext` class where you want to call the stored procedure, you can simply do:

```
var studentStuff = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Student>
("dbo.DoSomethingWithStudent @studentID", 
new SqlParameter("@studentID", studentID));
```

You can't pass a complex model directly to a SQL stored procedure.

If your procedure returns no results it would be:

```
    dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.DoSomethingWithStudent @studentID",
        new SqlParameter("@studentID", studentID));
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. So that means we cant send complex type to SP from EF. I have to move to ado.net and pass datatable as TVP to SP.

Comment: @user961372 No, this is still Entity Framework.  The DbContext class is specifically part of EF (it's in the System.Data.Entity namespace).  This is not raw ADO.Net.  Please accept my answer if you found it useful.